# How can I tell if a SQL Server MDF file is getting full/might need to grow?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know that the transaction log/ldf file fills up and grows and that I can see how full it is by running:

```
DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)
```

Is there a corresponding command to check on the status of the data/mdf file?

---

**Why I'm interested:**

I'm troubleshooting a simple .NET app that uses SqlBulkCopy to import data. Normally this works fine but occassionally the app fails with due to a timeout/SqlException (included below). I've increased the BulkCopyTimeout property and that hasn't solved the problem.

Looking through the SQL Server logs I see entries like these:

> Autogrow of file 'MyDatabase' in
>   database 'MyDatabase' was cancelled by
>   user or timed out after 29812
>   milliseconds.  Use ALTER DATABASE to
>   set a smaller FILEGROWTH value for
>   this file or to explicitly set a new
>   file size.

Which leads me to believe that my data file needs to grow (10% growth == a few GB) and that my bulk copy is failing while it waits for the MDF file to grow.

The .NET exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Timeout expired.  The t
>       imeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
>   server is not
>       responding.
>       The statement has been terminated.
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolea
>       n breakConnection)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObj
>       ect stateObj)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cm
>       dHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet
>   bulkCopyHandler, Tds
>       ParserStateObject stateObj)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternal()
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServer(Int32
>   columnCount
>       )
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable
>   table, DataRowSt
>       ate rowState)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 
`EXEC sp_spaceused`

but keep in mind that the database_size that it returns includes both data and logs..

more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
select sum (total_pages) from sys.allocation_units;
```

[`sys.allocation_units`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189792.aspx) keeps track of every allocated page in the database. If you want to be more specific, you're going to have to separate the allocation units per data space ([`sys.data_spaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190289.aspx)) in order to identify *which* filegroup is running out of space.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the file, the size , amount of storage used . and amount available;

```
SELECT    
[name] AS [File Name],    
physical_name AS [Physical Name],    
[Total Size_Mb] = ceiling([size]/128), 
[Space used_Mb] =    CAST(FILEPROPERTY([name], 'SpaceUsed') as int) /128,
[Available Space_Mb] = (([size]/128) - CAST(FILEPROPERTY([name], 'SpaceUsed') as int) /128) ,file_id
FROM sys.database_files   
ORDER BY [file_id]
```